# Use WHERE in an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to let users insert a subject to an image. I know I can't use a WHERE clause in combination with an INSERT INTO statement, and I know that I should use SELECT. I am very new to mysql and I didn't understand the results I tried to search on google. So I needed a more specific answer;)

```
$classed = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (subject) VALUES ('$_POST[subject]') WHERE image_id='$_POST[id]'");
```

Comment: `INSERT` is for creating new rows, `WHERE` is for finding existing rows. It's not clear what you're trying to do with the combination.

Comment: Never use unfiltered user input in database queries (SQL Injection danger!)

Comment: Are you looking to update an existing row? The (aptly named) command is `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `INSERT` in existing rows, try `UPDATE` the SQL will be something like

```
UPDATE images SET subject = '...' WHERE id=x;
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. It works for me. And as I said, I'm very new with Mysql. Learned a lot, thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting echo_Me answer's instead, it's better, more complete, includes php code and deals with the user input in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't use `WHERE` in your `INSERT` statement. Consider trying `UPDATE` if you want to update existing rows, or `INSERT` without the `WHERE` to insert new rows.
2. Don't use the `mysql_query` function, as it deprecated. Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead.
3. Don't **ever** use unfiltered input in your query.

Answer (score 2):

- if you already have `image_id` value then you should `UPDATE` your table not `INSERT`.
- you should escape your variables before inserting them in your table. by 
  `mysql_real_escape_string()`

try this:

```
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']) ;
$id      =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'] )   ;
$classed = mysql_query("UPDATE images 
                        SET subject = '".$subject."' 
                        WHERE image_id='".$id."' ");
```